# Does anyone know how to use the Options Clause in Google Sheets Query Function?

Tags: google-sheets

I've been studying the Query Function for quite some time now, but I still don't know how to use the Options Clause. Can someone explain how to use it? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation on:

#### [Data Table Class](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#datatable-class)

> Each cell in the table holds a value. Cells can have a null value, or a value of the type specified by its column. Cells optionally can take a "formatted" version of the data; this is a string version of the data, formatted for display by a visualization. A visualization can (but is not required to) use the formatted version for display, but will always use the data itself for any sorting or calculations that it makes (such as determining where on a graph to place a point). An example might be assigning the values "low" "medium", and "high" as formatted values to numeric cell values of 1, 2, and 3.

Within Google Sheets, however, it seems not to have any effect.

It is intended for the JavaScript Visualization API, and the sheets implementation of `QUERY` is similar but will not behave in exactly the same way. There is a corresponding method `setFormattedValue(rowIndex, columnIndex, formattedValue)` which allows you to set formatted values, if you want them. The example given in the docs says that instead of showing numbers, for the sake of a certain visualization you may want to display "high", "medium" or "low" instead.

#### In Sheets:

[image]

Using the `JOIN` function to get the raw values:

```
=JOIN(" ", QUERY(A:A,"Select A options no_values"))
and
=JOIN(" ", QUERY(A:A,"Select A options no_format"))
```

It will take the format of the first value and coerce the subsequent values into that format. Even the number at the end.

[image]

If you change the first value format:

[image]

You'll now get this:

[image]

In both cases you'll see that `options` has no effect.

Answer (score -1):

I've not used it, but this is the official description:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#options

Comment: Yes! I've read the description, and I've been trying it. I don't know what it really does. I've tried formatting the cells (i.e., color, number format, etc.) and use the Option Clause, but I don't see any changes in the results.

Comment: I've just tried it out and it is quite underwhelming! I can't get it to affect the data. I previously had issues with `format` not working as it should so it could be a glitch with the way it is implemented into Sheets. The documentation is not 100% relevant to Sheets - like the implementation of the `select` statement, so `options` are probably more relevant to Google Charts.